# My code finds values in the list, but does not show any prompt when the value is not found

Tags: python

I was trying to do a binary search on the list CardData=[11,12,25,33,52,56,57,59,85,91]

this is my binary search method

```
def binsea(x,CardData):
    front=0
    back=len(CardData)
    mid=len(CardData)//2
    found=False
    while front<back and found==False:
        if x==CardData[mid]:
            found=True
            print(x,"is found at position",mid)
        elif x<CardData[mid]:
            back=mid
            mid=(front+back)//2
        elif x>CardData[mid]:
            front=mid
            mid=(front+back)//2
        else:
            print(x,"not found.")
```

it can find the the data in the list but does not do anything with this call.

binsea(55,CardData)

plzzzz help

```
def binsea(x,CardData):
    front=0
    back=len(CardData)
    mid=len(CardData)//2
    found=False
    while front<back and found==False:
        if x==CardData[mid]:
            found=True
            print(x,"is found at position",mid)
        elif x<CardData[mid]:
            back=mid
            mid=(front+back)//2
        elif x>CardData[mid]:
            front=mid
            mid=(front+back)//2
        else:
            print(x,"not found.")
```

binsea(55,CardData)

i was expecting a output of "55 not found."

Comment: It's easy to understand why it doesn't work: your 3 if, elif, elif statements cover all the possible situations, so the else will never be executed! Furthermore, the loop with continue eternally with front, mid, back = 4, 4, 5.

Answer (score 0):

In general, I think the best way to debug your code yourself is often to add print statements. Try printing the values of front, back, and mid at the end of the loop (inside the loop). That should help you find your problem.

You could also look up the law of trichotomy.

Answer (score 0):

Your program is working. The condition `elif x<CardData[mid]:` will run as `x = 55` and `CardData[mid] = 56`
Add some print statements it's easy to figure out

Answer (score 0):

This one should work (though I didn't test it thoroughly); that said, a dichotomy search would be better suited by writing a recursive function.

```
def binsea(x,CardData):
    front=0
    back=len(CardData)
    mid=len(CardData)//2
    found=False
    while back - front > 1 and found==False:
        print 
        if x==CardData[mid]:
            found=True
            print(x,"is found at position",mid)
        elif x<CardData[mid]:
            back=mid
            mid=(front+back)//2
        elif x>CardData[mid]:
            front=mid
            mid=(front+back)//2
    else:
        if not found:
            print(x,"not found.")
```

Here's a working recursive approach (it returns the index of x in the original CardData list if found, else inf; you can then use the result in a print statement to get what you want):

```
from math import inf

CardData=[11,12,25,33,52,56,57,59,85,91]


def binsea(x,CardData):
    if not CardData:
        return inf
    mid = len(CardData)//2
    if x == CardData[mid]:
        return mid
    elif x < CardData[mid]:
        return binsea(x,CardData[:mid])
    else:
        return mid + 1 + binsea(x,CardData[mid+1:])
    

def message(x, CardData):
    index = binsea(x,CardData)
    if index == inf:
        print(f"{x} is not in {CardData}")
    else:
        print(f"{x} was found at index {index} in {CardData}")
        
message(33,CardData)
# 33 was found at index 3 in [11, 12, 25, 33, 52, 56, 57, 59, 85, 91]

message(55,CardData)
# 55 is not in [11, 12, 25, 33, 52, 56, 57, 59, 85, 91]
```

Of course, if the goal of all this is NOT to work on the dichotomy method,
Python allows a far simpler approach:

```
def is_in_list(x, CardData):
    try:
        print(f"{x} was found at index {CardData.index(x)} in {CardData}")
    except:
        print(f"{x} is not in {CardData}")
```